# why are we not encouraging posting answers as an answer but not via comments?

Tags: discussion, comments, answers

I have seen many cases, every time exact answers are posting via comments instead of answers. So I would like to get clarification, is that the encouraged way here?

I have seen at [Stack Exchange traffic portal](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) that unix.stackexchange.com has 77% questions answered and its better than other infamous sites like Ask Ubuntu and Stack Overflow.

Please encourage answering questions by posting answers instead of comments.

NOTE: All my thoughts are very clear and to make unix.stackexchange.com as a better place (of course it's already). I am not writing this to point anyone out intentionally.

Comment: When commenting, I am often phone bound, or doing some debugging/trial via comments, or have limited time and cannot provide a full answer, or do think the question/answer itself is not worth the investment to write a formal answer. Other people´s reasons should not be very different from mine.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Please see my answer for why this is harmful. (And note that we're having this conversation _up here_ as an example of the problem.)

Comment: Related http://meta.serverfault.com/a/1931/180142

Comment: Because otherwise people had one less reason to do downvotes, as self-answering your questions seems to be very frowned upon.

Comment: @sjas I didnt get you. Please explain clearly

Comment: From what I experienced, it is not worth the time to post solutions to your own problems, as they tend to receive downvotes mostly. People seem to think that you are a 'gold digger' for reputation points or something. I beg your pardon for my sarcasm in my last comment, I should have made that clearer.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

You're always encouraged to answer questions as actual answers and not simply as comments. But it's really up to the individual users of the site to put in whatever effort they are most comfortable with.

I would encourage you, or anyone that may come across this situation, to look at these comments as an opportunity to write them up as more complete answers yourself. I would ask the user who provided the comment first before doing so, but I've found most everyone here to be very encouraging to others, with respect to having others take their comments and convert them into formal answers.

Comment: So in this process do we have to take permission from user who wrote the answer as comment ?

Comment: @Raja - I would as a courtesy to the commenters. But as I said, most users of this site, I would expect, would be perfectly fine if someone were to do so.

Comment: Alright I will follow as you said, and thanks for editing my post. It's more meaningful now.

Comment: If they wanted the reputation award for themselves, they have an "answer" button too.

Comment: When posting someone else’s comment as an answer, you can make it a community wiki so that you don’t feel like "stealing" the answer.

Comment: It's clear this issue splits people, and it looks like it's a reasonably even split.  But for me, the collaborative element of Stackexchange is crucial, and answers, half-answers, ideas, theories and out-of-the-box wild theories as comments are all critical.  Sometimes I have an idea that'll solve the problem *if my assumptions are correct*, but I ask to confirm them first, and sometimes I'll ask if my assumptions are correct by posting a comment with the suggested solution and if it works, I'll write it up as answer.  I think it's a valuable tool in the process.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea. Sometimes I'll offer a comment that needs fleshing out. I may not have time, but want to try and help the OP. I've had several say that work's for me, make it an answer. After obliging, the experts chime in and poke holes in the answer (not POSIX, not my shell, etc). Now I often comment first, answer later, if at all.

Comment: @EightBitTony I don't see that as a problem; you're using the comments to clarify the question and work towards a better (actual) answer.

Comment: FWIW, I don't see it as all that evenly split. This top-voted answer is against comments as answers, but soft on it. My answer (second voted up, currently), is the hard-line don't-do-it. And the third — with many fewer votes — is still just "it's okay in some very particular situations". There's no "yes this is fine" answer at all.

Answer (score 34):

I am *very* opposed to answers as comments.

Using the comments robs us of the ability to vote up or down or suggest edits, and basically defeats the functioning of the Stack Exchange engine. And since comments on the question go above real answers, it's a way to get in a first word, which is unfair to the real answers.

I've seen many people say "But, I did that because I didn't have a complete or real answer". That's actually *worse*! Now these lower-quality partial answers come above the real ones, can't be voted on properly, and can't be improved.

Answer-comments also push down comments which might be used to get clarification and improve the question itself, so they distract from the actual intended purpose of comments to questions.

**If you have a good, succinct answer, please put it in the answer section.** If you know that your comment is an incomplete answer, it's probably best to think about how to round it out. Or maybe just let someone else answer. Or, if you really can't resist, think about coming back later after someone else answers and deleting your comment so it doesn't distract. Maybe it could even fit as an edit to another answer, or a comment to an answer, which is less harmful since at least the answer comes first.

<sub>Some of this answer was lifted from my post over at Photo SE, [Short answers as comments — please resist the urge](https://photo.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4655/short-answers-as-comments-please-resist-the-urge)</sub>

Comment: You've actually changed my opinion of "short rough answers as comments."  Excellent points.

Comment: I feel like the most ambiguity on this topics comes from a comment that turns into an answer. When possibly probing for more info, trying to figure out what they've tried out. (ex. `question: I'm having problem with my website comment: Have you tried restarting apache? reply: thanks, that fixed it.` In a scneario like this it makes most sense to follow up with an answer, either by the commenter or original asker. I feel if a comment happens upon the correct answer it can be fine to leave it, but an answer should be added as well.

Comment: @Dave Yeah, that case is... the least bad. :) I'd still prefer for the comments to be cleaned up, though, at least after the fact.

Comment: @mattdm Comments can still provide useful context after the fact, and since they can't be edited a little while after creation it can certainly be better to leave them sometimes than to delete them. It's all situational of course, I feel like if comments were editable longer after creation this could be solved, so that information relevant to the answer could be moved out, and leave anything else intact.

Comment: Dunno, I like to comment when I'm giving vague or uncertain answers to avoid downvotes in case I'm off. The reason this is good is because stack exchange has this shitty system in place that locks you from asking questions if you've received too many downvotes. Would you rather I not post at all when I only have a vague idea of an answer?

Comment: @Cestarian Yes! If you don't know what you are talking about, don't answer. You aren't helping by guessing. You can call this all the swear words you want, but it's still true. If you are consistently getting enough downvotes, you're either not thinking about what you are posting or are actually not qualified to make this kind of call.

Comment: I don't think I agree with that philosophy. If I have a vague idea about what I'm talking about and nobody has given any answers, I should try to help, I would want you to do the same for me. Not knowing what I'm talking about, and having a vague idea about it are different things. What's with the condescending attitude?

Comment: @Cestarian In that case, try for an answer, for the reasons I've given.

Comment: I'm sorry that feels condescending, but the goal of the site is to help people with clear answers they can trust. Putting *uncertain* answers which can't be edited or voted down ***above*** the real answers is not helping at that goal, and doing it explicitly to avoid downvotes is gaming the system.

Comment: I'd argue it is using the system to it's fullest, not "gaming" it. If you have something to add that you don't think qualifies as a full answer, why not post it as a comment? There are disadvantages to comments of their own (for example not all viewers will read the comments, and even those who do may only read the top 2-3 comments; and if you get a lot of upvotes for a good comment, what is wrong with that?) also if all you want is to score points, comments are the worst way to do it since you only get like 2 points per upvote right? Answers get 10, if that's not encouragement idk what is.

Comment: @Cestarian You specifically said that you want to post these uncertain answers in a way that avoids triggering the site's protective features if the community finds them unhelpful. That's gaming the system.

Comment: @mattdm like I said, that's using the system not gaming it. What are comments for if not posting incomplete answers, and answers you think might work but aren't sure would. Enforcing this somehow to get more users to provide incomplete junk as answers would probably only be bad in the long run, and users who are getting banned for the downvotes on said answers will just make new accounts to circumvent the (stupid) bans that are placed on them. It's not gonna solve anything, it's not gonna make anything better. And why does it matter so much if people read some comment before an answer?

Comment: I covered that, but I'll repeat: Comments are for clarifying and improving the question or answer being commented on. Answers are for answers. It matters because the entire goal of the site is to present clear-cut questions and direct answers without distracting baggage. By adding noise, you're reducing the signal.

Comment: Isn't guessing part of the trouble shooting process, especially when the person with the problem doesn't fully understand what the problem is? Although, I do agree that the problem is that we cannot downvote comments.

Comment: @mchid But are you troubleshooting, or just providing a low-effort answer? That is, will a response by the original questioner provide information that will improve a full answer, or are you effectively dropping the mic and walking out?

Comment: @r-m No, if anything, it seems that it is more often the OP that drops the Mic or just doesn't want to put in the effort to work things out. Although, I have much more experience on askubuntu and I have found this is not as much of a problem on unix.stackexchange.

Comment: Yeah, Stack Exchange isn't ideal for interactive troubleshooting. My suggestion is to focus comments on clarifying questions and ask for the details to be added to the question, not a back and forth in comments — and then erase them and provide an answer. If the questioner doesn't return, vote to close as unclear. I don't see any need to provide guesses as comments as part of this process — if there's enough that your diagnostic process might be useful to some future viewers, *make it an answer*.

Comment: I think a dogmatic approach like this harms the overall process.  If I'm in a room with people and someone asks a question, and I have an idea but don't say anything, then it doesn't help spark further ideas in other people.  The end game on this site is to answer questions in a useful way, but the process can be collaborative, and if it's not, the output is less rich.  We should accept that some people aren't going to write answers, or some people want to propose ideas for others to develop, and if we stifle that, I personally feel we lose some value.

Comment: @EightBitTony Can you explain why you can't do that with answers?

Comment: @mattdm because you're clearly against half-formed answers as answers as well - and so am I, I don't think writing 'you could probably do this with `some-obscure-tool` I remember but I can't find the man page right now' as an answer is wise.  But I might write it as a comment and hope someone else recognises `some-obscure-tool` and writes up an answer with it.  I know you've already responded to that above, and disagree with it, and that's fine, but I feel that your suggested approach is dogmatic, restrictive and unhelpful overall.

Comment: I also don't personally feel that comments carry more weight than answers, I'm a reader of StackExchange sites as well as a contributor, and I read the top voted answer long before I read any comments.  The only thing that frustrates me is answers which have comments which significantly improve the answer without being folded in.  Answers under the original question, I just ignore unless the accepted answer doesn't help.

Comment: `"But, I did that because I didn't have a complete or real answer". That's actually worse! Now these lower-quality partial answers come above the real ones, can't be voted on properly, and can't be improved.` The comments aren't all loaded by default, nor do I bother to read them half the time. However, if there aren't any good answers, it can be helpful if someone said "I'd guess the problem has something to do with foo". Would it be ideal if they rounded that out? Sure! But help is help, and if the options are "some help" v. "all or nothing", I'm accepting "some help" every time.

Comment: If a full answer takes 20 minutes to write, and a quick comment that provides 90% of the information necessary to solve the problem takes 30 seconds, instituting a policy against such comments wouldn't result in a larger number of helpful answers, it'd just result in a smaller number of helpful comments. Because most of the people who would leave a 30-second comment aren't going to write a 20-minute answer.

Comment: @ParthianShot That seems irrelevant to the issue here. If you can give a 90% answer in 30 seconds, you can write it in the space marked "answers".

Comment: I find this _really_ important. We have a Q&A model for a reason. Let's not break that model out of laziness. If you don't have time to write an answer, _don't_! Let somebody else do it. http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/247446/155739

Comment: Because of this answer, I just wrote [this](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268287/135943) as a brief answer instead of doing what I would have done previously and posting it as a comment.

Comment: thought to say, I find it annoying that everybody expects some long formal answer with step-by-step instructions for babies. I think that one should be greatful even for an answer with 3 words that gets you going.

Answer (score 8):

I believe there are legit reasons to provide an answer (or sometimes a hint) in a comment if:

- the question should not be answered (it's silly, duplicate, off-topic etc.) and either
- the question lacks basic understanding but is asked in good faith and deserves at least a hint, or
- the question asks about something dangerous and a quick warning is in order

This way, the question can still be safely deleted, but the OP gets at least some reward for their effort. And if he's about to do something dangerous, he gets warned quickly (this applies more to EE.SE, where people ask things like "I'm trying to connect this circuit to 220 Volts", and you instantly see they shouldn't, but I can imagine similar cases relevant to U&L).

Additionally, it also happened to me to see a question I didn't know the answer for, see the comments, google around and finally post a complete answer based on someone else's comment. I don't see anything wrong with this practice, and nobody ever told me that I've stolen their answer, so I don't agree that comments discourage real answers to be posted. On the contrary, if the author of the comment didn't write it, the OP wouldn't probably get a full answer at all, or at least not as quickly.

Comment: I definitely understand the impulse, because we're here to help, but if the question is _bad_ (silly, duplicate, etc.), doesn't answering anyway (in a comment or otherwise) just encourage the behavior? ("I know this isn't supposed to be allowed, but I get what I want when I do it, so I'll keep it up.")

Comment: I often can tell between lazy and clueless. It's bad to encourage the former, but the latter sometimes deserves some guidance, even if the question itself is of little interest to others and should be removed. I agree with you that posting answers in comments should not be done in cases where regular answers are in order, but I don't see the problem with someone providing a quick hint in a comment and someone else elaborating that hint in an answer. The comment itself may be removed afterwards, especially if it is misleading or obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with this point.  I'm actually wondering, given that:

- We can flag questions as "not really a question" (a.k.a. "unclear what you're asking")
- We can mark answers as "Please ask this as a separate question"
- We can mark answers as "Please use comments for this"

And a typically seen response to questions given in comments is:

- "Please ask this as a new question rather than posting it in comments",

So why, then, don't we have the ability to **flag a comment as "this should be posted as an answer"**?

Just mathematically, there are three things—questions, comments, answers.  That gives 6 ways you can mix things up by confusing one for another.

- Whether a non-question is a comment or an "answer", it gets marked the same ("unclear what you're asking"), which takes care of 2 out of 6.
- Answers that aren't answers are either comments or questions (the same question or a different one) and get handled either way.
- Comments that are actually answers are the **1/6th** of the possible mixups and the only one that we don't have clear-cut community agreement on how to handle.

**If you have even a *partial* answer, post it with the button marked "Post Your Answer.**

That way we can use votes, suggested edits, comment on your answer, link to it semi-permanently; it will be indexed properly for search engines; etc., etc., etc.